# Is the position of space and time precisions in this sentence correct?

Tags: indications-de-temps, ordre-des-mots, indications-de-lieu

Today I was sitting on a bench in the Public Garden in the city of Boston when a beautiful girl and her boyfriend sat down beside me, speaking French. Simultaneously I noticed there were six or seven other people around, taking photos and feeding ducks, all speaking French.

I ended up asking the guy next to me in English, but what I had wanted to say was:

> Pourquoi est-ce qu'il y a tant de gens là qui parlent français aujourd'hui?

I was really uncertain of the word order, in terms of where to put *là* and *aujourd'hui*.

Was  I right?

Comment: The order is good, but It would be better to say "Pourquoi y a-t-il tant de gens ici qui parlent français aujourd'hui ?". And even here, having a temporal AND spatial precisions seems a bit "heavy" I would certainly remove "ici" and keep it implicit to lighten the sentence.

Comment: A link on when to use "est-ce que"  vs. subject-verb inversion : http://grammaire.reverso.net/3_1_27_est-ce_que.shtml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the word order is correct. The complement of time has to be at the end of the sentence. The complement of place has can be just after *gens* and before the phrase that qualifies it, or it can be part of the second clause: “*Pourquoi est-ce qu'il y a tant de gens qui parlent français ici aujourd'hui?*”. I can't explain why these locations work and others don't.

The word *là* should be *ici* instead. It's happening here, not there.

Comment: I was under the impression *là* is used to mean *here* in most casual speech...I hear *Je suis là* very often. Am I misunderstanding? Also, is there a typo? You wrote "it can be part of the ."

Comment: @Aerovistae I don't know what happened, I restored the missing fragment. *Être là* is an idiom, meaning to be present. There can be ambiguity as to whether something is far away to be *là* instead of *ici*, but I can't think of a case where *là* would be more casual and *ici* more formal.

Comment: So-- the moral of the story is I *can* say *là* here, or can't? It seems to me that this idiomatic usage is approximately correct here-- "Why are there many people present who speak French?"

Comment: @Aerovistae You have to say *ici* if you're in the park and refering to the people around you. On the other hand, if you were talking about it after leaving the park, you'd have to use *là* or *là-bas* (“*Je me demande pourquoi il y avait tant de gens qui parlaient français là-bas* tout à l'heure*”). At least in France, I don't know if it's different in Québec. Oh, and why *là-bas* and not *là*? I'd have to think about it.

Comment: Intuitivement j'emploie *ici* si je suis inclus dans le lieu (ou le groupe) dont il est question, sinon le *là* s'impose.