# A beggar's cardboard in French

Tags: usage

I too was in the central park and I also faced a situation which demanded knowledge of French like the user Aerovistae ([Is the position of space and time precisions in this sentence correct?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7337/is-the-word-order-in-this-sentence-correct)).

This time, however, I was approached by a non-French speaking beggar who wanted me to write something for his cardboard.

So here is what I wrote for him:

> Je suis XXX. J'ai une famille avec cinq enfants mais je n'ai maison et
>   nouritture. J'ai besoin de votre aide, s'il vous plait.

How could I have written a better paragraph (perhaps in terms of politeness) so that it could have given him the maximum benefit? Also, what do you think of what I wrote, is it correct?

Comment: On a meta level, though, if the beggar you happen to walk by in the street has a sign with excellent grammar and vocabulary, the overall impression of dire need is somewhat lost. Could it be better to "save" a few mistakes for relevance ? Just a thought.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is pretty close to what a French speaker would have written, but there are still a few mistakes. Remember that I am only commenting "how" you should have written, not "what", which is irrelevant here.

*Je suis* is seldom used in French to give your name, unless the person you are talking to is supposed to know this name. *Je m'appelle* is more common.

*J'ai une famille avec cinq enfants* is correct, yet a bit awkward. *Je suis père d'une famille de cinq enfants* would be better in my opinion.

*mais je n'ai maison et nouritture* is incorrect. *mais je n'ai **ni** maison, **ni nourriture*** would be correct. Take note that *maison* refers to a house (quite expensive), *logement* would be a more generic wording (but perhaps a little too formal). *Abri* (shelter) works as well.

Finally, I believe ending the message by *Merci.* would be regarded as more polite.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. But one might understand more polite forms of expression by this exercise, if one knows what would be the best way to ask for favours.

Comment: The best way is not necessarily the most polite. If the country's culture has strong christian roots, one could try *Dieu vous le rendra* ("God will give it back", that is, he will reward the donor). It might be effective, depending on both sides' beliefs. But it's only an example.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility. I don't know if there is a best way to ask:

> Je m'appelle xxx. Je suis père d’une famille de cinq enfants. Je n’ai pas les ressources pour les loger et les nourrir. Pourriez-vous me venir en aide ? Merci pour votre générosité.