# What is the most polite way to ask for money?

Tags: vocabulaire, politesse

*The answer needs to be in French, I am Francophone, but my English skills are better, so I'll ask the question in English.*

What is the most polite way to ask someone (not a close friend) for money? It's like a donation, not a loan. I think in English  they say *chip in* or maybe there's a better expression. It's like financial aid. What I come up with is

> J'aimerais savoir si vous pouvez m'aider en envoyant xx dollars.

Comment: You'll need to provide more context. Is it going to be spoken, or written? In a formal document, an email, a note?

Comment: @AlexisPigeon written in an email, formal but not so formal, the other person is a friend, but we haven't spoke for a long time

Comment: Smells like a scam in preparation :P

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt [funny](http://memecrunch.com/meme/14HIK/keep-digging/image.png)

Comment: The only polite way is not to ask for money in the first place ...

Comment: @jlliagre - Surtout lorsqu'on reprend contact avec un ami perdu de vue depuis longtemps...

Comment: This might also help: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7344/a-beggars-cardboard-in-french.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Pouvez-vous, s’il vous plait, me venir en aide d’X dollars ?

You can use « S’il vous plait » or « Je vous prie ».

Comment: shouldn't I use Le conditionnel? pour exprimer un souhait? or it doesn't make a difference here?

Comment: Not realy. The conditionnel isn’t important here.

Comment: Est-ce une expression québécoise ? En tant que français, je trouve la formulation *Pouvez-vous, s’il vous plait, me dépanner d’X dollars ?* plus naturelle bien que moins soutenue.

Comment: Aucunement, même si souvent les gens pensent que je suis québécois (Alors que je n’ai jamais posé les pieds sur la Belle Province ni dans le reste du Canada) :)
Mais le verbe « dépanner » n’a pas sa place ici puisque @Fischer demandais justement la façon la plus soutenue de formuler cette requête.

Answer (score 2):

Pourriez-vous contribuer (à la lutte contre la faim / à lutter contre le nucléaire) en m'envoyant XX dollars.